# How do you build a turabian-thesis template when using chapters?

Tags: pdftex

I'm having trouble building a simple turabian-thesis template that uses chapters.  Here is a minimal working example (MWE) demonstrating the problem I am having.

**document.tex**

```tex
\documentclass{turabian-thesis}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes, ellipsis}
\usepackage[pass, letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\title{Turbian-formatted Thesis/Dissertation}
\subtitle{A Template based on Turabian's \emph{A Manual for Writers}, 9th edition}
\author{Author's Name}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle

% Abstract
\chapter*{Abstract}

\lipsum[1][1]

A citation example\autocite{citekey}.

% Dedication
\cleardoublepage
\begin{center}
    \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
    
    To [Name]
    
    \vspace*{\stretch{2}}
\end{center}
\cleardoublepage

\tableofcontents
\listofillustrations

\mainmatter

% Introduction
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

\lipsum[1][1]

% Chapter 1
\chapter{A First Chapter}

\section{An Interesting Section}

\lipsum[1][1]

\section{Another Insightful Section}

\lipsum[1][1]

% Chapter 2
\chapter{Another Great Chapter}

% Conclusion
\chapter*{Conclusion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusion}

\lipsum[1][1]

\backmatter
\begin{appendixes}

    \chapter{First Appendix}

    \chapter{Second Appendix}

\end{appendixes}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**bibliography.bib**

```tex
@article{citekey,
  title={SuperCoolTitle},
  author={Ima Author},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Silly Journal}
}
```

**SConstruct**

```python
PDF('document.tex')
```

Here is the output I get when I build.

```
>> scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
cd . && pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -recorder document.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/local/bellockk/Development/MWE/document.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-04-06>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/turabian-formatting/turabian-thesis.cl
s
Document Class: turabian-thesis 2020/03/19 Turabian Theses and Dissertations
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk12.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/turabian-formatting/turabian-formattin
g.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/setspace/setspace.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/footmisc/footmisc.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ellipsis/ellipsis.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/biblatex-chicago.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/chicago-notes.bbx)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/chicago-notes.cbx)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.ltd.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nowidow/nowidow.sty)
No file document.aux.
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/cms-american.lbx
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/american.lbx
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx))
No file document.bbl.
[1{/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'citekey' on page 2 undefined on input line 24.

[2] [3]
No file document.toc.
[4]
No file document.lof.
No file document.lot.
[5] [1]
Chapter 1
! Extra \else.
\NR@chapter ... \tf@endnotesection {#1} \fi \else 
                                                  \addcontentsline {toc}{cha...
l.49 \chapter{A First Chapter}
                              
! Extra \fi.
\NR@chapter ...ontentsline {toc}{chapter}{#1} \fi 
                                                  \chaptermark {#1} \@makech...
l.49 \chapter{A First Chapter}
                              
[2]
Chapter 2
! Extra \else.
\NR@chapter ... \tf@endnotesection {#1} \fi \else 
                                                  \addcontentsline {toc}{cha...
l.60 \chapter{Another Great Chapter}
                                    
! Extra \fi.
\NR@chapter ...ontentsline {toc}{chapter}{#1} \fi 
                                                  \chaptermark {#1} \@makech...
l.60 \chapter{Another Great Chapter}
                                    
[3] [4]
Appendix A
! Extra \fi.
\tf@endnotesection ...@enotesechead {#1}} \fi \fi 
                                                  
l.71     \chapter{First Appendix}
                                 
[5]
Appendix B
! Extra \fi.
\tf@endnotesection ...@enotesechead {#1}} \fi \fi 
                                                  
l.73     \chapter{Second Appendix}
                                  

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 77.

[6] (/local/bellockk/Development/MWE/document.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                document
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/share/texlive/texmf-d
ist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fo
nts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/ty
pe1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbxti10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/
public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/
amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfont
s/cm/cmr8.pfb>
Output written on document.pdf (11 pages, 68659 bytes).
Transcript written on document.log.
pdflatex returned an error, check the log file
scons: *** [document.pdf] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Can anyone provide some guidance on building this template when using chapters?  If I replace all the calls to chapter with section, the document will build, but I'm hoping to use both chapters and sections as described in the style's [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/turabian-formatting?lang=en).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With version 2020/03/19 of the `turabian-formatting` package, there was a bug that:

> ... prevented typesetting documents with turabian-thesis that
> have chapter headings where the endnotes formatting option is not used.

This seems to be the cause of the errors indicated in the output you shared.

The bug was fixed with version 2021/03/20 of the package. The latest version of `turabian-formatting` is available at: https://ctan.org/pkg/turabian-formatting or through the TeX Live Utility.

I tried compiling your sample code with this latest version, and it works great.